# Custom serialisation for CSV with Jackson

Tags: java, csv, jackson, fasterxml

So, imagine I have following Java classes:

```
public class A {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = PropertiesSerializer.class)
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Properties properties;
}

public class Properties {
    List<Property> properties;
}

public class Property {
    String key;
    String value;
}

class PropertiesSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Properties> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Properties properties, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) {
        if (properties != null && properties.getProperties() != null) {
            properties.getProperties().forEach(property -> {
                try {
                    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                    jsonGenerator.writeStringField(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
                    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What I need here is to serialize the `Product` object to CSV. When trying to run it, I get `CSV generator does not support Object values for properties (nested Objects)` error. When adding `@JsonUnwrappped` annotation to lower level objects, I still get stuck at some point with the same error.

Shouldn't it ignore everything and call the custom serializer for the `properties` field? It looks like it completely ignores this method. How do I fix that?

Btw, I can't change the code structure because of the XML conversion.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Currently the json that your code generates looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": "myId",
    "name": "myName",
    {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    {
        "foo2": "bar2"
    },
    ...
}
```

I think you are just missing `jsonGenerator.writeArrayFieldStart("properties")` before the loop and `jsonGenerator.writeEndArray()` after the loop.